# How to loop through ViewData with Javascript in ASPX View

Tags: javascript, asp.net, local-storage, viewdata

I have populated `ViewData` item with an array of questions so that I can store the json data in local storage:

```
string[] jsonQuestions = new string[StudentExam.QuestionCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < StudentExam.QuestionCount; i++)
            {
                jsonQuestions[i] = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(StudentExam.QuestionsE[i]);

                ViewData[i.ToString()] = jsonQuestions[i];
            }
```

During testing I loaded the `ViewData` into the `localstorage` like this (hard coded) for the exact amount of questions:

```
            localStorage.setItem("obj0", JSON.stringify(<%=ViewData["0"]%>));
             localStorage.setItem("obj1", JSON.stringify(<%=ViewData["1"]%>));
             localStorage.setItem("obj2", JSON.stringify(<%=ViewData["2"]%>));
             localStorage.setItem("obj3", JSON.stringify(<%=ViewData["3"]%>));
             //...etc.
```

In the view I am trying to now dynamically load the `ViewData` into the browser `localstorage` like this using javascript:

```
<script>

         var mod = "<%=Html.Raw(Model.TotalNumberOfQuestionsForTest.ToString())%>";


         for (var i = 0; i < mod; i++) {

             localStorage.setItem(
                 "obj" + i.toString(),
                 JSON.stringify(<%=ViewData[i.toString()]%>));

         };
    </script>
```

Now this gave me an error that it cannot find `i`, since we "escaped" the client side code. So I changed it to :

```
for (var i = 0; i < mod; i++) {

             var s = <%=ViewData[%>i.toString()<%]%>;

             localStorage.setItem(
                 "obj" + i.toString(),
                 JSON.stringify(<%=ViewData[%>i.toString()<%]%>));

         };
```

This is the part where I'm stuck at. I keep getting these errors on this line:

`JSON.stringify(<%=ViewData[%>i.toString()<%]%>));`

> Error 7   Invalid expression term ';'

and

> Error 8   ; expected

and when I run the web app this is all I get on inspect element:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 278:             localStorage.setItem( Line 279:
>   "obj" + i.toString(), Line 280:
>   JSON.stringify(<%=ViewData[%>i.toString()<%]%>)); Line 281: Line 282:
>   };

Is there a way to escape the `<%%>` tags, into the javascript again for the javascript variable to use in the ViewData? Or another way to do this?

UPDATE:
I went on and played around with the code a bit more and this is the closest I have gotten to what I need to happen by doing it like this:

```
$(function () {

             <% for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){%>
         <%="localStorage.setItem('obj" + i.ToString() + "',JSON.stringify('"%><%=ViewData[i.ToString()]%>"'))"

            <%}%>

         });
```

So this does loop through my questions and put the value in where I needed, but the last issue I have is that now by having to put the javascript in quotations :

```
<%="localStorage.setItem('obj" + i.ToString() + "',JSON.stringify('"%><%=ViewData[i.ToString()]%>"'))"
```

The last quotation mark is needed to close the string between the `<%%>` tags. but this quotation mark is giving me the error:

> Invalid or unexpected token

as my javascript to store the `localstorage` looks like this now:

```
localStorage.setItem("obj1", JSON.stringify("my json query"))" //this quotation is the problem
```

Any assistance or help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fix the problem. The issue with the quotation was that I was "stringifying" a string and the moment I removed the single quotation marks from the code:

```
$(function() {    
            <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.TotalNumberOfQuestionsForTest; i++){%>
            <%="localStorage.setItem('obj" + i.ToString() + "',JSON.stringify("%>
            <%=ViewData[i.ToString()]%>
            <%="))"%>
           <%}%>
```

The `json` object was successfully stored in the `localstorage` of the browser.